# PhpStorm: Dead keys not working (for ', ", etc)

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, input, ide, java

I'm using Elementary OS Loki on my Dell XPS 9550.

The keyboard layout I'm using is English (US, International with dead keys). This works perfectly in every application I have tested so far.

However, when I try to type in my IDE, PhpStorm (based on IntelliJ IDE), the special characters such as ' and ` do not register.

Normally these are done with a combination keypress, even for single quotes. For example:

' + space = '

" + space = "

In PhpStorm, the first keypress seems to be ignored completely. Pressing space afterwards just results in an actual space.

Any advice on fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: I should note that switching to a US keyboard layout that does not use dead keys works around this issue, but I would prefer to not resort to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by executing `ibus-setup` in a terminal.

Source:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/774237/dead-keys-accents-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04

To fix it permanently you need to figure out how to start `ibus-deamon` on system startup (I haven't quite figured that one out yet).

Comment: Can you mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a workaround, but I switched to a **keyboard layout with no dead keys** - as I anyways never use them (and it's still possible to type them using compose key).

This way a press on the keyboard directly inserts the acute character.